# Salt concentration in flowing water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> A basin contains $N_s(t)$ moles of salt dissolved in $N_w(t)$ moles of water. The basin receives fresh water at a constant rate $\Omega_w^{in}$. This water is assumed to be thoroughly mixed in the basin so the salt concentration is homogeneous. The salty water comes out of the bassin at a constant rate $\Omega_{sw}^{out}=\Omega_s^{out}(t)+\Omega_w^{out}(t)$. Determine the salt concentration $c_s(t)=\dfrac{N_s(t)}{N_s(t)+N_w(t)}$.

We have $\dot{N}_w(t)=\Omega_w^{in}-\Omega_w^{out}(t)$ and $\dot{N}_s(t)=-\Omega_s^{out}(t)$ so that $N_{sw}(t)=N_S(0)+N_w(0)+\left(\Omega_w^{in}-\Omega_{sw}^{out}\right)t$.

At $t+dt$, we have $N_w(t+dt)=N_w(t)+(\Omega_w^{in}-\Omega_w^{out}(t))dt$ and $N_s(t+dt)=N_s(t)-\Omega_s(t)dt$ so that $c_s(t+dt)=\dfrac{N_s(t+dt)}{N_s(t+dt)+N_w(t+dt)}=\dfrac{N_s(t)-\Omega_s(t)dt}{N_w(t)+(\Omega_w^{in}-\Omega_w^{out}(t))dt}$. How do I continue?

Comment: Hint: this is the classic problem where the concentration of salt water is related to the rate of fresh water entering the basin, assuming that the level in the basin is constant.  Set this up as a differential equation, and look for an answer that involves exponential decay.

Comment: @DavidWhite You mean $\dot{N}_s(t)=kN_s(t)$?

Comment: Yes.  That's your starting point.